# Laravel output model ordered by related table column

Tags: php, laravel

I have this query filter which works fine to query out the result. For example, if I need to find books which have the Author name something:

```
Book::with('user', 'author')
    ->whereHas('author', function ($query) use($filters) { 
        $query->filter($filters);
     })->paginate(30);
```

But the thing is if I want to order the Books by the author names. I this case nothing happens.

How can I sort books by author name?

QueryFilter looks like this:

```
public function  __construct(Request $request) {
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->filterService = new FilterService();
}

public  function apply(Builder $builder) {
    $this->builder = $builder;
    foreach ($this->filters() as $name => $value) {
        if (method_exists($this, $name)) {
            call_user_func_array([$this, $name], array_filter([$value]));
        }
    }
    return $this->builder;
 }

 public function filters() {
     return $this->filterService->removeEmptyFieldsFromRequest($this->request);
 }
```

And the book filter looks like this:

```
public function date($date) {
    return $this->builder->where('date', $date);
}

public function name_sort($order = 'asc') {
    return $this->builder->orderBy('name', $order);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use class join statement :

```
$books = Book::select('author.name AS author_name, countries.*')
  ->with('user')
  ->join('author', 'author.id', '=', 'book.author_id')
  ->orderBy('author.name', 'ASC')
  ->paginate(10);
```

Comment: You are right, but it's only the idea. Then, yes you have to test if you have `author` joined by adding for example `->has('author')`

Comment: Ok, long time I didn't use Laravel. I edited my answer, I will try on a new 5.* project.

Comment: The thing is that I have a Table with all the books and info (author name, author birthday and many more author info). On the page, I have a filter which allows to search by author name and author info. What if I use filter then want to sort the result by author name?

Comment: It seems you must use class join statement. When you use relation with Eloquent, it doesn't grab the other table, but create several queries.

Comment: Complicated... `author.name`  that means I can sort only name field? I have many fields i want to sort: ))))

Comment: Ok. I got it!! I will just join the tables and will work with that result!